# Finding the difference between two values in a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, array-difference

I have a numpy list which I initiate by (my_array=[] and has a shape of (0,)) then I append the wm and hm elements to it like so(r is a cascade with the format of-[[300 240 22 22]]):

```
my_array=[]
for (x, y, w, h) in r:
    wm=int(x+ (w/2.))
    hm=int(y+ (h/2.))
    my_array.append([numpy.float32(wm), numpy.float32(hm)])
return numpy.array(my_array)
```

That code produces:

```
wm element       the hm element
[[270.01 303.43] [310.17 306.37]] # second to last row
[[269.82 303.38] [310.99 306.86]] # the last row
the shape of the returned array is (2,2) and is dtype:float32
```

...

Now the problem is that when I tried to append the 303.43 it theoratically would be [-2][1] but it indexes 303.38. which is fine but I also need to index 303.43 aswell.

**What I found was that the first [] indexes either the wm[0] or hm[1] element, then the second [] indexes one of the two columns of values inside each element**
-for example [0][-1] indexes the wm element[0] and last row [-1] I want to index the second last row aswell and tried [0][-2] but it didnt work as intended(it indexed the 269.82).

So I tried [0][1][-2] but it didnt work due to IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

All I want to do is to find the difference between the last and second to last row for the 2 columns in the wm element(so in the example above it would be 269.82-270.1=-0.19 and 303.38-303.43=-0.05). The indexing doesn't work. So is there a way around this problem?

Comment: A previous question with the same array: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153448/indexing-appended-elements-from-a-numpy-array-python

Comment: Show an `r`, and the result of the function (`my_array`).  We need to be able to recreate your array.  In your previous questions it was hard to sort out your use of 'row', 'column' and indexing.

Comment: @PyDeve1opper did any of the solutions worked? If yes you should mark it to let other users know about it if they encounter your same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making 3 'r' values:

```
In [798]: r=np.array([[300, 240, 22, 22]])+np.array([[0],[2],[3]])              
In [799]: r                                                                     
Out[799]: 
array([[300, 240,  22,  22],
       [302, 242,  24,  24],
       [303, 243,  25,  25]])
```

your loop produces:

```
In [800]: my_array=[] 
     ...: for (x, y, w, h) in r: 
     ...:     wm=int(x+ (w/2.)) 
     ...:     hm=int(y+ (h/2.)) 
     ...:     my_array.append([numpy.float32(wm), numpy.float32(hm)]) 
     ...:                                                                       
In [801]: my_array                                                              
Out[801]: [[311.0, 251.0], [314.0, 254.0], [315.0, 255.0]]
```

As an array:

```
In [802]: arr = np.array(my_array)                                              
In [803]: arr                                                                   
Out[803]: 
array([[311., 251.],
       [314., 254.],
       [315., 255.]], dtype=float32)
```

2nd to the last row

```
In [804]: arr[-2,:]                                                             
Out[804]: array([314., 254.], dtype=float32)
```

last row:

```
In [805]: arr[-1,:]                                                             
Out[805]: array([315., 255.], dtype=float32)
```

Their difference:

```
In [806]: arr[-2,:]-arr[-1,:]                                                   
Out[806]: array([-1., -1.], dtype=float32)
```

first column:

```
In [807]: arr[:,0]                                                              
Out[807]: array([311., 314., 315.], dtype=float32)
```

2nd column

```
In [808]: arr[:,1]                                                              
Out[808]: array([251., 254., 255.], dtype=float32)
```

See your previous question for a similar answer:

[Indexing appended elements from a numpy array python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55153448/indexing-appended-elements-from-a-numpy-array-python)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't reproduce your array but given your (very convoluted) question I believe that the following will do what you ask in the end:

This should give you `269.82-270.1=-0.19`

```
my_array[0][-2]-my_array[0][0]
```

and this should give you `303.38-303.43=-0.05`

```
my_array[0][-1]-my_array[0][1]
```

In general I believe that you index your array `my_array` as follows:

```
               wm element                       the hm element
[[my_array[0][0]   my_array[0][1]]   [my_array[1][0] my_array[1][1]]] # second to last row
[[my_array[0][-2]  my_array[0][-1]]  [my_array[1][-2] my_array[1][-1]]] # the last row
```

In your particular case the second to last element is also the third so you could index them as `my_array[0][2]` instead of `my_array[0][-2]` and `my_array[1][2]` instead of `my_array[1][-2]`