# Finding the difference between two values in a numpy array-with code

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, opencv, indexing

I have a numpy list which I initiate by (my_array=[] and has a shape of (0,)) then I append the wm and hm elements to it like so(r is a cascade with the format of-[[300 240 22 22]]):

```
my_array=[]
for (x, y, w, h) in r:
    wm=int(x+ (w/2.))
    hm=int(y+ (h/2.))
    my_array.append([numpy.float32(wm), numpy.float32(hm)])
return numpy.array(my_array)
```

That code produces:
wm element       the hm element
[[270.01 303.43] [310.17 306.37]] # second to last row
[[269.82 303.38] [310.99 306.86]] # the last row
the shape of the returned array is (2,2) and is dtype:float32

Now the problem is that when I tried to append the 303.43 it theoretically would be [-2][1] but it indexes 303.38. which is fine but I also need to index 303.43 as well.

## What I found was that the first [] indexes either the wm[0] or hm[1] element, then the second [] indexes one of the two columns of values inside each element

-for example [0][-1] indexes the wm element[0] and last row [-1] I want to index the second last row as well and tried [0][-2] but it didn't work as intended(it indexed the 269.82).

So I tried [0][1][-2] but it didn't work due to IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.

All I want to do is to find the difference between the last and second to last row for the 2 columns in the wm element(so in the example above it would be 269.82-270.1=-0.19 and 303.38-303.43=-0.05). All solutions presented in other questions dont work ([0][-1],[-1][0], you can try them yourself to find out) The indexing doesn't work. So is there a way around this problem? Please explain it fully because I am still kind of new to this! Thanks in advance!

Addition:
Taking the last two blocks of data
Indexing the array (in the idle) fetches(I copied the last two blocks of the array):
   `[[293.51373 323.4329 ]
  [247.77493 316.02783]]`

```
[[292.9887  322.23425]
 [247.24142 314.2921 ]]
```

On my program, it shows up as (the same array)
--wm element------------------hm element
`[[293.51373 323.4329 ][247.77493 316.02783]]`   I consider this the second to last row
`[[292.9887  322.23425][247.24142 314.2921 ]]`   and I thought this was the last row

This brought forth a lot of confusion for me, but I ignored the minor difference of the way they are displayed until now. Now, the question is how to index the 323.4329 and the 293.51373 numbers, it would be better if they can be indexed separately?

Comment: Continuation of https://stackoverflow.com/q/55435119

Comment: `arr[-1, 0]` is the last row, first column, the `wm` one.  `arr[-2,1]` is 2nd to the last row, 2nd column, `hm`.

Comment: Did you try the code?arr[-2,1]shows up as the second column and presumably, the last row of wm and arr[-1,0]is the first column and last row of hm that is whats confusing. For that reason, I wanted help and even gave the code so people can try it out for themselves and find this strange anomaly. I tried every indexing combination of[x,y], it either gave an error of axis being 1or it indexes something different. That's why I need somebody to help. All of the proposed indexing methods above or previously don't work for the indexation of the second to last row, as previously stated.

Comment: It could be that the axis is 1 so I can't index the second to last row. Appending elements doesnt add a new row, it just updates the current value. So, I tried different methods which didn't work. Now I am here trying to see how to do this either with a different appending method or indexing method.

Comment: Your array is 2 dimensional, with`wm` values in the 1st column, `hm` values in the 2nd.   `arr[:0]` fetches all `wm` values.  `arr[-1,:]` fetches the last last appended `(wm,hm)` pair.

Comment: I tried arr[:0] and it fetched []. Arr[-1,:] showed the hm values and [-2,:] showed wm values. I tried different ways of indexing [-1,:],[-2, :1] etc. None of which worked. If you try the code it will tell you the results I am getting just without a bar to indicate which value goes where. Although you can print the whole array and then also print the indexing method your trying and see if they line up. Do I need to switch my appending method or is there another indexing method which I haven't tried (I've tried a lot). Thanks for replying and hopefully we can resolve this problem.

Comment: Sorry, I missed a comma.  `arr[:,0]` to index a column of `arr`.  `arr[:0]` selects of size 0 slice of the `arr` rows.  How am I supposed to try your code with all this `cv` stuff?  I tried to recreate your `Li` array in previous answers.

Comment: I am sorry for making it complicated with the cv stuff but all you need to do is do pip install opencv-python and then download the xml file. But I do understand if you don't want to. The arr[:,0] does fetch the first values of both wm and hm. Then [-1,:] indexes the first and second hm values. I might not be understanding this whole indexing but all the indexing methods don't index the second to last row on any column. All I want to know is how to index the second to last row of a column. If you can help me with that it would be fantastic. Thanks again for bearing through this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sample `r`:

```
In [41]: r = np.array([[0,0,8,10],[1,1,6,8],[2,2,10,12]])                            
In [42]: r                                                                           
Out[42]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  8, 10],
       [ 1,  1,  6,  8],
       [ 2,  2, 10, 12]])

In [43]: my_array=[]                                                                 
In [45]: for (ex,ey,ew,eh) in r: 
    ...:     wm = int(ex+(ew/2)) 
    ...:     hm = int(ey+(eh/2)) 
    ...:     print(wm,hm) 
    ...:     my_array.append([wm,hm]) 
    ...:                                                                             
4 5
4 5
7 8
```

The resulting array:

```
In [46]: arr = np.array(my_array)                                                    
In [47]: arr                                                                         
Out[47]: 
array([[4, 5],
       [4, 5],
       [7, 8]])
```

Sample indexing:

```
In [48]: arr[:,0]                                                                    
Out[48]: array([4, 4, 7])   # the 3 wm values
In [49]: arr[-1,:]          # the last values produced by the last `r` row                                                         
Out[49]: array([7, 8])
```

Or a more symbolic array:

```
In [52]: arr = np.array([[f'wm{i}',f'hm{i}'] for i in range(3)])                     
In [53]: arr                                                                         
Out[53]: 
array([['wm0', 'hm0'],
       ['wm1', 'hm1'],
       ['wm2', 'hm2']], dtype='<U3')
In [54]: arr[:,0]                                                                    
Out[54]: array(['wm0', 'wm1', 'wm2'], dtype='<U3')
In [55]: arr[-1,:]                                                                   
Out[55]: array(['wm2', 'hm2'], dtype='<U3')
```

===

```
In [108]: arr = np.array([[313.5536, 330.60587], [368.23245, 332.70932]])            
In [109]: arr                                                                        
Out[109]: 
array([[313.5536 , 330.60587],      # 2nd to the last row
       [368.23245, 332.70932]])     # last row
```

Last row:

```
In [110]: arr[-1]                                                                         
Out[110]: array([368.23245, 332.70932])
In [111]: arr[-1,:]                                                                  
Out[111]: array([368.23245, 332.70932])
```

First column

```
In [112]: arr[:,0]                                                                   
Out[112]: array([313.5536 , 368.23245])
```

2nd to the last row:

```
In [113]: arr[-2,:]                                                                  
Out[113]: array([313.5536 , 330.60587])
```

Comment: `arr- [[313.5536  330.60587]  
 [368.23245 332.70932]]   
arr[-1] -[368.23245 332.70932]    
arr[:,0]- [313.5536  368.23245]    
arr[-1,:] -[[368.23245 332.70932]]`  These are the results taken straight from the code, so it can help you get a better understanding of what's going on. Hopefully, this helps and if it does I can show you other indexing methods and what they produce!

Comment: Copied your values to my answer.  Indexing the 2nd to the last row, i.e. first row in this 2 row case, is pretty obvious to me.

Comment: Well, if it was that simple I wouldn't be asking for help. But maybe I was looking it the wrong way. On the program, it shows the array as a straight line, so I thought that the indexing uses the straight line indexes. So if we had a couple of consecutive rows then I can index them as if they are in a straight line, thus being confused with the "weird indexes" that the indexing methods fetch. But on the idle program, it shows as a 2 line array(instead of a single line)which I thought is just how it shows. If that's the case then sorry for confusing you. And thanks for sticking with me!

Comment: `It shows`?  Do you mean in a plot or image?  The array you give may define some corner points for a box or something like that, but indexing the array only gives those points, not lines within or bounding the box.  You'd have to use some sort of image or plotting code to interpolate points along a line.

Comment: I could have looked at this the wrong way. Which with some indexing does seem to be the case.  But my problem still stands. Just in a different way. Now I can explain it better and correctly. I will do it in addition to the question so I can properly format everything

Comment: With the addition to my question hopefully, you can understand what my problem is and the necessary indexing method. I again want to apologize for my confusion, I was looking at the wrong format of the array the whole time judging from it.